# Build Angular Store with Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, store, ngrx-store

I have this Angular app in which I want to create a custom store for chat objects.

(**codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/chat-store-yw4yz**)

> *Note: I know there are tools like ngrx but this is part of a bigger project and I would prefer to use this custom implementation so I understand better the behaviour of the store.*

### Context

The idea to make it quick and efficient is to have into the store two types of records:

- A dictionary (as a Map) with `key = chat id` and `value = chat object`
- An index (as a Map) for grouping chats by *groupId*, where `key = groupId` and `value = chatId`

So I have this interface definition:

```js
export interface ChatStoreModel {
  chats: Map<number, Chat>;
  chatsByGroup: Map<number, number[]>;
}
```

When a chat object is saved into the Store two things should happen:

- chat object is saved into store `chats`
- chat id is saved into store `chatsByGroup` in the corresponding *groupId*

### Problem

It is not working to get the chat objects from a group. I do the following:

- get chat ids list from store `chatsByGroup` using groupId
- for each chat id, get element from store `chats`

Code:

```js
getGroupChats$(groupId: number): Observable<Chat[]> {
    return this._store.select("chatsByGroup").pipe(
      map((chatsByGroup) => chatsByGroup.get(groupId) || []),
      switchMap((ids) => {
        if (!ids || !ids.length) {
          return of([]);
        }
        const chatsList$: Observable<Chat>[] = ids.map((id) =>
          this._store.select("chats").pipe(map((chats) => chats.get(id)))
        );
        return forkJoin([...chatsList$]).pipe(
          map((list) => {
            return ([] as Chat[]).concat(...list);
          })
        );
      }),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
  }
```

Debugging this code, it reaches the line with `return forkJoin` and ids have the list of chats but it never reaches the line `map((list) => {` so the app does not display the chat list.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whenever any of that observables completes without emitting any value,
> forkJoin will complete at that moment as well and it will not emit
> anything either

This is from the [RxJS ForkJoin Doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin). My guess is that the one of the Observable that you pass to the `forkJoin` completes without emitting anything, thus `forkJoin` instantly completes without emitting anything.

Try using `defaultIfEmpty` operator to be sure that this situation doesn't happen. I suggest doing something like so:

```
const chatsList$: Observable<Chat>[] = ids.map((id) =>
  this._store.select("chats").pipe(map((chats) => chats.get(id))),
  defaultIfEmpty(null),
);
```

---

> forkJoin will wait for all passed observables to complete

This is again from the docs. This means that all of the Observables that you pass to the `forkJoin` have to complete in order for the `forkJoin` to emit value itself.

My guess is that `this._store.select("chats").pipe(map((chats) => chats.get(id))),` this line will run endlessly so you need to provide `take(1)` for it to be completed, otherwise `forkJoin` won't emit anything. So try something like this:

```
const chatsList$: Observable<Chat>[] = ids.map((id) =>
  this._store.select("chats").pipe(map((chats) => chats.get(id))),
  take(1),
  defaultIfEmpty(null),
);
```

---

Lastly if you don't want to use `take(1)`, by which I mean you want to be subscribed to the Observable as long as it is emitting values, you might want to use `combineLatest` instead of `forkJoin`. That's because `forkJoin` waits for the completion to emit something, while `combineLatest` will emit the latest values of the provided Observables.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Also, if I want to listen to changes to each chat object, I should not use `take(1)`, right?

Comment: @adrisons Yes that's right, `take(1)` will only pass one value and then complete.